# Promote our site and get an Announcer or a Booster badge

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, badges

Stack Exchange awards badges to people who promote our site.

- The [**Announcer** badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question that is later visited by 25 unique IP addresses**.
- The [**Booster** badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question later visited by 300 unique IP addresses**.
- The [**Publicist** badge](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses**.

Each of these badges can be awarded multiple times. At the time of writing (August 2017), only one person on our site has been awarded a promoter badge.

I will create two answers to this question:

- one with a lists of the first ten people on our site who get an Announcer badge, and
- one with a list of the first ten who get a Booster badge.

**How do you share a link to get one of the site promotion badge?**

The link should be created be clicking on the `share` link below a question or an answer. This will generate a link that contains your user ID, so the system can track who shared the link. For example, if I click on the `share` link below this question, I get the following URL: `https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/573/800`. The number `573` represents the question; the number `800` represents my user ID on Literature Stack Exchange. You can share this kind of link on social media or on other sites that get a lot of traffic.

(This question was inspired by [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/10067).)

Comment: Time to use my secret Twitter account that was supposed to be for this site

Answer (score 1):

### First Twenty to Get an Announcer Badge

1. [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) (4 Jan 2017: [How can watching movies help improve fluency and listening skill?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-can-watching-movies-help-improve-fluency-and-listening-skill))
2. Hatchet (7 Sep 2017: [Is there an assumption you've learnt something before putting it on Anki?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/953/is-there-an-assumption-youve-learnt-something-before-putting-it-on-anki))
3. Hatchet (21 Sep 2017: [How can flashcards be made using only the target language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/how-can-flashcards-be-made-using-only-the-target-language))
4. Christophe Strobbe (8 Nov 2017: [Additional sentences for language deconstruction (CEFR levels A1-A2)?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2308/additional-sentences-for-language-deconstruction-cefr-levels-a1-a2))
5. Christophe Strobbe (11 Jan 2018: [Are there any accurate online resources for learning to write Devanagari?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2984/800))
6. [bytebuster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/60/bytebuster) (22 Jan 2018: [Learning a language, for someone who can't stand flash cards](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3182/800))
7. [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) (4 October 2018: [What approaches can I take to overcome 'leeches'?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/219/what-approaches-can-i-take-to-overcome-leeches))
8. [TRIG](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/74/trig) (4 December 2018: [Why do experts recommend learning Esperanto?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3/800))
9. Christophe Strobbe (31 January 2019): [How long between each HSK level for learning Mandarin?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3638/800)
10. [Greek - Area 51 Proposal](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/90/greek-area-51-proposal?tab=badges) (24 February 2019): [How can I develop an accent in a foreign language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-can-i-develop-an-accent-in-a-foreign-language)
11. [atroviridis](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7330/atroviridis) (12 Dec 2019: [answer to the question 'Is there any software for minimal-pair training?'](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/393/is-there-any-software-for-minimal-pair-training/2776#2776))
12. [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) (17 May 2020: [answer to the question 'How can I strengthen vocabulary knowledge of words learned with flash cards?'](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/331/how-can-i-strengthen-vocabulary-knowledge-of-words-learned-with-flash-cards/332#332))
13. [Tsundoku](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/tsundoku) (27 May 2020: [Which SRS algorithm yields greatest evidence-based remembering](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3757/800))
14. [TRiG](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/74/trig) (10 Oct 2020: [answer to the question 'Why do experts recommend learning Esperanto?'](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-do-experts-recommend-learning-esperanto/56#56))
15. [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) (1 Nov 2020: [Are there any studies which address the effectiveness of studying multiple related languages simultaneously?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-any-studies-which-address-the-effectiveness-of-studying-multiple-relat))
16. [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) (14 Dec 2020: [How does a paid online tutor compare to a language exchange partner?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-does-a-paid-online-tutor-compare-to-a-language-exchange-partner))
17. ?
18. ?
19. ?
20. ?

Comment: Why are 4 over 7 questions in here all about flashcard?

Comment: @Ooker I hadn't even noticed. Clearly a sign of the popularity of flashcards.

Comment: Would it be a sign of small area of interest I language learning?

Answer (score 0):

### First Ten to a Get Booster Badge

1. [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) (9 March 2020: [Is there an assumption you've learnt something before putting it on Anki?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/953/800))
2. [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) (10 March 2020: [How can flashcards be made using only the target language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2248/800))
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?